# Refreshing MSSQL Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql-server

When working on a map in QGIS I will often set up a view in my SQL Server spatial database and create a MSSQL layer based on this.

As part of my workflow I often make adjustments to the SQL view based on input from the client.

Is there a quick way of refreshing the layer in QGIS so that it picks up on these changes? Currently I end up closing and re-opening my project to pull any changes through.